How to fix build error on vercel of Next.js project
When I try to deploy Nextjs project to vercel, such errors are occuring. All were good with deployment, but once I clicked "Instant rollback" by chance, all the deployment fails now showing such errors:
[01:18:05.538] Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1 [01:18:05.684] Cloning github.com/BTC415/Nextjs-Supabase-Blog (Branch: main, Commit: 40caf96) [01:18:06.025] Cloning completed: 340.953ms [01:18:06.058] Previous build cache not available [01:18:06.363] Running "vercel build" [01:18:07.076] Vercel CLI 36.0.0 [01:18:07.473] Running "install" command: `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`... [01:18:11.719] npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported [01:18:13.071] npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful. [01:18:13.364] npm warn deprecated glob@7.1.7: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported [01:18:15.525] npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/object-schema@2.0.3: Use @eslint/object-schema instead [01:18:15.555] npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/config-array@0.11.14: Use @eslint/config-array instead [01:18:31.903]  [01:18:31.904] added 826 packages, and audited 827 packages in 24s [01:18:31.904]  [01:18:31.905] 273 packages are looking for funding [01:18:31.905]   run `npm fund` for details [01:18:31.947]  [01:18:31.947] 5 vulnerabilities (1 high, 4 critical) [01:18:31.948]  [01:18:31.948] To address all issues (including breaking changes), run: [01:18:31.948]   npm audit fix --force [01:18:31.948]  [01:18:31.948] Run `npm audit` for details. [01:18:31.981] Detected Next.js version: 14.0.2 [01:18:31.988] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+ [01:18:31.989] Running "npm run build" [01:18:32.124]  [01:18:32.124] > ubdotcafe@0.1.0 build [01:18:32.124] > next build [01:18:32.124]  [01:18:32.720] Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage. [01:18:32.720] This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features. [01:18:32.721] You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL: [01:18:32.721] https://nextjs.org/telemetry [01:18:32.721]  [01:18:32.817]    ▲ Next.js 14.0.2 [01:18:32.818]  [01:18:32.818]    Creating an optimized production build ... [01:19:00.865] Failed to compile. [01:19:00.866]  [01:19:00.866] ./icons/loading-dots.module.css [01:19:00.866] Error: Cannot find module '@tailwindcss/typography' [01:19:00.866] Require stack: [01:19:00.866] - /vercel/path0/tailwind.config.js [01:19:00.867]     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15) [01:19:00.867]     at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:54:36 [01:19:00.867]     at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/helpers:190:19) [01:19:00.867]     at _resolve (/vercel/path0/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:241814) [01:19:00.867]     at jiti (/vercel/path0/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:244531) [01:19:00.867]     at /vercel/path0/tailwind.config.js:82:5 [01:19:00.867]     at evalModule (/vercel/path0/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:247313) [01:19:00.867]     at jiti (/vercel/path0/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:245241) [01:19:00.867]     at /vercel/path0/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/load-config.js:37:30 [01:19:00.867]     at loadConfig (/vercel/path0/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/load-config.js:39:6) [01:19:00.868]  [01:19:00.870] Import trace for requested module: [01:19:00.870] ./icons/loading-dots.module.css [01:19:00.870] ./icons/loading-dots.tsx [01:19:00.871] ./icons/index.ts [01:19:00.871] ./components/shared/shared-not-found.tsx [01:19:00.871] ./components/shared/index.ts [01:19:00.871] ./app/not-found.tsx [01:19:00.871]  [01:19:00.871] ./icons/loading-dots.module.css [01:19:00.871] Error: Cannot find module '@tailwindcss/typography' [01:19:00.871] Require stack: [01:19:00.871] - /vercel/path0/tailwind.config.js [01:19:00.871]     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15) [01:19:00.871]     at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:54:36 [01:19:00.871]     at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/helpers:190:19) [01:19:00.872]     at _resolve (/vercel/path0/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:241814) [01:19:00.872]     at jiti (/vercel/path0/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:244531) [01:19:00.872]     at /vercel/path0/tailwind.config.js:82:5 [01:19:00.872]     at evalModule (/vercel/path0/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:247313) [01:19:00.872]     at jiti (/vercel/path0/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:245241) [01:19:00.872]     at /vercel/path0/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/load-config.js:37:30 [01:19:00.872]     at loadConfig (/vercel/path0/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/load-config.js:39:6) [01:19:00.872]  [01:19:00.872] Import trace for requested module: [01:19:00.872] ./icons/loading-dots.module.css [01:19:00.872] ./icons/loading-dots.tsx [01:19:00.872] ./icons/index.ts [01:19:00.873] ./components/shared/shared-not-found.tsx [01:19:00.873] ./components/shared/index.ts [01:19:00.873] ./app/(main)/category/[...slug]/error.tsx [01:19:00.873]  [01:19:00.873] ./icons/loading-dots.module.css [01:19:00.873] Error: Cannot find module '@tailwindcss/typography' [01:19:00.873] Require stack: [01:19:00.873] - /vercel/path0/tailwind.config.js [01:19:00.873]     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15) [01:19:00.874]     at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:54:36 [01:19:00.874]     at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/helpers:190:19) [01:19:00.874]     at _resolve (/vercel/path0/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:241814) [01:19:00.874]     at jiti (/vercel/path0/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:244531) [01:19:00.874]     at /vercel/path0/tailwind.config.js:82:5 [01:19:00.874]     at evalModule (/vercel/path0/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:247313) [01:19:00.874]     at jiti (/vercel/path0/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:245241) [01:19:00.874]     at /vercel/path0/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/load-config.js:37:30 [01:19:00.874]     at loadConfig (/vercel/path0/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/load-config.js:39:6) [01:19:00.874]  [01:19:00.874] Import trace for requested module: [01:19:00.874] ./icons/loading-dots.module.css [01:19:00.874] ./icons/loading-dots.tsx [01:19:00.874] ./icons/index.ts [01:19:00.875] ./components/shared/shared-not-found.tsx [01:19:00.875] ./components/shared/index.ts [01:19:00.875] ./app/api/og/route.tsx [01:19:00.875] ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-app-loader.js?name=app%2Fapi%2Fog%2Froute&page=%2Fapi%2Fog%2Froute&pagePath=private-next-app-dir%2Fapi%2Fog%2Froute.tsx&appDir=%2Fvercel%2Fpath0%2Fapp&appPaths=%2Fapi%2Fog%2Froute&pageExtensions=tsx&pageExtensions=ts&pageExtensions=jsx&pageExtensions=js&basePath=&assetPrefix=&nextConfigOutput=&preferredRegion=&middlewareConfig=e30%3D!./app/api/og/route.tsx?__next_edge_ssr_entry__ [01:19:00.875]  [01:19:00.877]  [01:19:00.877] > Build failed because of webpack errors [01:19:00.940] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1 [01:19:01.383] 

It works well on my local pc, but it doesn't work on vercel.
I mean, I have tried to build and start on my local pc, it quite works well without any errors.
But always fail on vercel.
Please help me fix this bug.
Thank you in advance
